# Retrieve property categories of selected item in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Using the `getProperties()` function I get an item with the `properties` array.

Inside each property, I have a variable called `displayCategory`.

Is there a way of listing the different `displayCategory` of an item?

Thanks.

Comment: Other than iterating through all properties and build a list of existing displayCategories, I hardly see another way to do it... Do you have a problem with that approach or are you looking for a more optimized way? You could use the Model Derivatives API to do that kind of pre-computation server side: http://autode.sk/2yR8Uc8

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma I was looking for a more optimized way of doing it but I'm probably just going to iterate through all the properties. I don't want to make calls to the Model Derivatives API unless there's no other way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Philippe Leefsma has stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929827/retrieve-property-categories-of-selected-item-in-viewer?noredirect=1#comment80819763_46929827) comment, the possible solutions are:

- Iterate through the properties array and group them by category.
- Call [this](http://autode.sk/2yR8Uc8) Model Derivatives API endpoint

I ended up iterating through the aray using `lodash`. Here's the code:

```
this.viewer.getProperties(object,
        function(item) {
          item.properties = _.chain(item.properties)
            .groupBy('displayCategory')
            .toPairs()
            .map(function(property) {
              return _.zipObject(['displayCategory', 'properties'], property);
            })
            .value();

        that.selectedItems.push(item);
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```